# Rewrite this INSERT *without* the subquery, please?

Tags: sql-server, insert, subquery

How would this INSERT statement be rewritten without the subquery, so it no longer results in the error "Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed"?

```
INSERT INTO FUNCTIONAL_AREA (
  FUNCTIONAL_AREA_UUID
  ,FUNCTIONAL_CATEGORY_UUID  
  ,CREATE_DATETIME 
  ,CREATE_USER 
  ,LUPDATE_DATETIME
  ,LUPDATE_USER 
  ,DESCRIPTION
  ,ITEM_CODE
  ,IS_ACTIVE 
) VALUES ( 
 NEWID()  
 ,(select functional_category_uuid from functional_category where description = 'ADLs')
 ,GETDATE()
 ,'11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111'
 ,GETDATE()
 ,'11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111'
 ,'Bathing - Ability' 
 ,1081
 ,1)
```

Thank you!

Comment: select NEWID()  
 ,functional_category_uuid,GETDATE()
 ,'11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111'
 ,GETDATE()
 ,'11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111'
 ,'Bathing - Ability' 
 ,1081
 ,1 from functional_category where description = 'ADLs'

Comment: Well, does the subquery return more than one row? Do you intend to insert one row or multiple?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO FUNCTIONAL_AREA (
  FUNCTIONAL_AREA_UUID
  ,FUNCTIONAL_CATEGORY_UUID  
  ,CREATE_DATETIME 
  ,CREATE_USER 
  ,LUPDATE_DATETIME
  ,LUPDATE_USER 
  ,DESCRIPTION
  ,ITEM_CODE
  ,IS_ACTIVE 
)
select NEWID()  
 ,functional_category_uuid 
 ,GETDATE()
 ,'11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111'
 ,GETDATE()
 ,'11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111'
 ,'Bathing - Ability' 
 ,1081
 ,1
from functional_category 
where description = 'ADLs'
```

**EDIT** Adding:

If you only want one row inserted and you care about which row is selected from functional_category, then either narrow the where clause so only one row comes back, or use an order by and top 1:

```
INSERT INTO FUNCTIONAL_AREA (
  FUNCTIONAL_AREA_UUID
  ,FUNCTIONAL_CATEGORY_UUID  
  ,CREATE_DATETIME 
  ,CREATE_USER 
  ,LUPDATE_DATETIME
  ,LUPDATE_USER 
  ,DESCRIPTION
  ,ITEM_CODE
  ,IS_ACTIVE 
)
select top 1 NEWID()  
 ,functional_category_uuid 
 ,GETDATE()
 ,'11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111'
 ,GETDATE()
 ,'11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111'
 ,'Bathing - Ability' 
 ,1081
 ,1
from functional_category 
where description = 'ADLs'
order by <criteria that causes the correct row to be first>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this error is because the VALUES clause restricts you to inserting one row. When you have a subquery as one of the columns then this could result in more than one value.

You could either do a 'select' insert like others have shown, or you could write the value to a variable and use the TOP 1 clause if the subquery returns more than one row.

Answer (score 0):

Just a little correction if you want to insert exactly one row in all cases:

```
INSERT    INTO FUNCTIONAL_AREA (
          FUNCTIONAL_AREA_UUID,
          FUNCTIONAL_CATEGORY_UUID,
          CREATE_DATETIME,
          CREATE_USER,
          LUPDATE_DATETIME,
          LUPDATE_USER,
          DESCRIPTION,
          ITEM_CODE,
          IS_ACTIVE)
SELECT    TOP (1) NEWID(),
          functional_category_uuid,
          GETDATE(),
          '11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111',
          GETDATE(),
          '11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111',
          'Bathing - Ability',
          1081,
          1
FROM      functional_category 
WHERE     description = 'ADLs'
```

or

```
DECLARE @category_uuid uniqueidentifier

SELECT    @category_uuid = functional_category_uuid
FROM      functional_category 
WHERE     description = 'ADLs'

INSERT    INTO FUNCTIONAL_AREA (
          FUNCTIONAL_AREA_UUID,
          FUNCTIONAL_CATEGORY_UUID,
          CREATE_DATETIME,
          CREATE_USER,
          LUPDATE_DATETIME,
          LUPDATE_USER,
          DESCRIPTION,
          ITEM_CODE,
          IS_ACTIVE)
VALUES(   NEWID(),
          @category_uuid,
          GETDATE(),
          '11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111',
          GETDATE(),
          '11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111',
          'Bathing - Ability',
          1081,
          1)
```